# Querying Datatable DBNull using Linq Query

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a DataSet which contains a datatable called Vacs and it has a date column called VacDate which in some cases it holds null value.

Now when i try to query it using linq query i got the following exception

> The value for column \'VacDate \' in table \'Vacs\' is DBNull

My Code is:

```
var Vacs = new MyDataSetTableAdapter.MyVacsTableAdapter();
DataTable Vacations = Vacs.GetData()
       .Where(s => s.VacDate == DateTime.Now)
       .ToList()
       .CopyToDataTable();
```

I did try the following but still getting the same error

```
DataTable Vacations = Vacs.GetData()
       .Where(s => s.VacDate != null && s.VacDate == DateTime.Now)
       .ToList()
       .CopyToDataTable();
```

I believe the solution would be simple but still i dont see it till now.

Thank you in advance.

Best regards...

Comment: try to use `s.VacDate != DBNull` instead of `s.VacDate != null`

Comment: Is `VacDate ` nullable type?

Comment: What is returned by `GetData()` method? Also seems like `Vacs` is not `DataTable` - from naming it is something like `DataAdapter`, but again there is no `GetData()` method in default `DataAdapter`.

Comment: @ShaminderSAujla I cant compare System.DateTime to DBNull or DBNull.Value

Comment: show your `GetData()` function body

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy GetData would return all rows in table, in case the datefield is null it will return the following exception for the field

    '(new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView<HR_Application.HR_DataSet.Hre_Vacation_TransRow>(tt)).Items[0].VacDate' threw an exception of type 'System.Data.StrongTypingException'

Comment: @ShaminderSAujla You mean this 

 public virtual HR_DataSet.Hre_Vacation_TransDataTable GetData() {
            this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[0];
            HR_DataSet.Hre_Vacation_TransDataTable dataTable = new HR_DataSet.Hre_Vacation_TransDataTable();
            this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);
            return dataTable;
        }

Comment: is your `GetData()` method is returning `datatable` successfuly ?

Comment: @ShaminderSAujla yes it does

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell what is implementation of your `MyVacsTableAdapter` class. Seems like problem is in it's implementation - when you get `VacDate` property value you are not handling DbNull case. Anyway - it's easy to do such filtering with LINQ to DataSet. If `Vacs` is simple `DataTable` then creating new DataTable with only rows matching some condition looks like:

```
DataTable allVacations = new DataTable(); // get filled DataTable
DataTable nextVacations = allVacations.AsEnumerable()
                             .Where(r => r.Field<DateTime?>("VacDate") >= DateTime.Today)
                             .CopyToDataTable();
```

LINQ can handle DbNull case and convert cell value to appropriate data type.

Note: You are using `DateTime.Now` in your condition check. It's very unlikely that some time value will perfectly match ticks of current time at the moment of comparison. You should probably use `>=` or `<=` operator here. Or compare just date.

Comment: Dude i love you, you really saved my day